# In processing , why movie.jump() function not work during movie reverse?

Tags: processing, movie

I am working on movie in processing. The move.jump() function not working during movie reverse play. And I have reverse code:
(The `reverse` is global boolean variable)

```
float playSpeed = 1.0;
//After click reverse button
if(reverse == false){
    playSpeed = playSpeed * -1; 
    movie.speed(playSpeed);
    reverse = true;
}
else{
      playSpeed = playSpeed * -1;
      movie.speed(playSpeed);
      reverse = false;
    }
```

During `reverse == true` I click some button, and jump to a time, for example 5.0, code is show below:

```
//after click button
if(reverse == true){
   movie.jump(5.0);
}
```

And this jump function is not work. It not jump to the movie frame which at 5.0 second. And show some error:

```
ast_segment_set_seek: assertion 'start <= stop' failed
```

Can anybody tell me why the jump function not work and how to fix it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: more reasonable answer: Could it be that jump calculates the position in relation to the frame rate which becomes negative when playing backwards and then end is before start? In this case my workaround should work.

Not sure what classes you are using, but couldn't you just make a workaround? Should be so fast the user won't notice:

```
if (reverse) {
    movie.speed(1f);
    // jump();
    movie.speed(playSpeed);
} else {
    // jump();
}
```

Btw reverse can be written as (no if needed):

```
reverse = !reverse;
playSpeed = -playSpeed;
movie.speed(playSpeed);
```

Comment: I use the Movie class in processing, and there are jump function. It should jump anywhere the time you want. Here is doc from official web: Jumps to a specific location within a movie. The parameter where is in terms of seconds. For example, if the movie is 12.2 seconds long, calling jump(6.1) would go to the middle of the movie.

Comment: Could it be that you first have to set the frame rate?

Comment: Your anwer that you found by yourself is exactly what i proposed long ago, except that mine is cleaner!

Answer (score -1):

I know the answer, I figure out by myself.
If movie play speed is less 0, the star will less than stop.
So, if the play speed is less 0, just * -1, let greater than 0, than jump, than * -1, let speed less than 0.

```
if(reverse == true){
          m.speed(playSpeed*-1);
          m.jump(5.0);
          m.speed(playSpeed*-1);
        }
```